# How do allow spaces in textinput.number in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-input

In TextInput.number, although I add space in the RegExp in FilteringTextInputFormatter, my iPhone or the simulator for the matter does not show the space in the keyboard for me to press. It only shows numbers. Is there a workaround or is there another input type I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, `TextInputType.number` provides you with the space button (looks a bit like an underscore).

Comment: Thank you for this. I just ran it on an Android Simulator and it works. What about iOS though? Is it only me or does Flutter not really work well with iOS or the other way around?